# What is pandas' transpose equivalent in Julia

Tags: pandas, julia

What is `pandas`' transpose equivalent in `Julia`? thanks

I like to transpose a data frame and `transpose` function isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `permutedims`, it turns a data frame on its side such that rows become columns and values in the column become the names.

Comment: The reason why `transpose` does not work is that it is recursive. in Julia `permutedims` is not recursive and this is a behavior that is typically expected by users.

Comment: @BogumilKaminski, what do you mean for "recursive" in this context?

Comment: I will answer in the answer as it is a longer issue.

Answer (score 5):

Note the difference between `transpose` and `permutedims` in Julia Base. `permutedims` only affects the outermost container. `transpose` is recursive.

Here are the consequences:

```
julia> x = [randstring(3) for _ in 1:3, _ in 1:3]
3×3 Matrix{String}:
 "nTa"  "QBM"  "3dJ"
 "RsL"  "mD1"  "3jq"
 "dFp"  "bfB"  "k6P"

julia> permutedims(x)
3×3 Matrix{String}:
 "nTa"  "RsL"  "dFp"
 "QBM"  "mD1"  "bfB"
 "3dJ"  "3jq"  "k6P"

julia> transpose(x)
3×3 transpose(::Matrix{String}) with eltype Union{}:
Error showing value of type LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Union{}, Matrix{String}}:
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching transpose(::String)

julia> y = [rand(3) for _ in 1:3, _ in 1:3]
3×3 Matrix{Vector{Float64}}:
 [0.446435, 0.653228, 0.0857836]  [0.378189, 0.505487, 0.0504642]  [0.0570918, 0.462984, 0.800813]
 [0.801857, 0.75505, 0.714087]    [0.253316, 0.458364, 0.80242]    [0.93742, 0.699745, 0.140957]
 [0.419783, 0.22946, 0.748267]    [0.445365, 0.563222, 0.363561]   [0.088825, 0.0869342, 0.311187]

julia> permutedims(y)
3×3 Matrix{Vector{Float64}}:
 [0.446435, 0.653228, 0.0857836]  [0.801857, 0.75505, 0.714087]  [0.419783, 0.22946, 0.748267]
 [0.378189, 0.505487, 0.0504642]  [0.253316, 0.458364, 0.80242]  [0.445365, 0.563222, 0.363561]
 [0.0570918, 0.462984, 0.800813]  [0.93742, 0.699745, 0.140957]  [0.088825, 0.0869342, 0.311187]

julia> transpose(y) # note that inside we have 1x3 objects not vectors
3×3 transpose(::Matrix{Vector{Float64}}) with eltype LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Float64, Vector{Float64}}:
 [0.446435 0.653228 0.0857836]  [0.801857 0.75505 0.714087]  [0.419783 0.22946 0.748267]
 [0.378189 0.505487 0.0504642]  [0.253316 0.458364 0.80242]  [0.445365 0.563222 0.363561]
 [0.0570918 0.462984 0.800813]  [0.93742 0.699745 0.140957]  [0.088825 0.0869342 0.311187]
```

In DataFrames.jl we decided that this recursive behavior (which makes sense in linear algebra context) is not desirable. You can even read this in the docstring of `transpose` which states:

> This operation is intended for linear algebra usage - for general data manipulation see permutedims, which is non-recursive.

Additionally in DataFrames.jl `permutedims` requires you to specify the column which will become column names after the operation (this requirement is DataFrames.jl specific) and you need to be careful as `eltype` promotion is performed (this issue is not visible for matrices which have a common eltype for all elements, while in a data frame each column might have a diffeent eltype):

```
julia> df1 = DataFrame(rowkey=["x", "y"], b=[1.0, 2.0], c=[3, 4], d=[true, false])
2×4 DataFrame
 Row │ rowkey  b        c      d
     │ String  Float64  Int64  Bool
─────┼───────────────────────────────
   1 │ x           1.0      3   true
   2 │ y           2.0      4  false

julia> df2 = permutedims(df1, :rowkey)
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ rowkey  x        y
     │ String  Float64  Float64
─────┼──────────────────────────
   1 │ b           1.0      2.0
   2 │ c           3.0      4.0
   3 │ d           1.0      0.0

julia> permutedims(df2, :rowkey)
2×4 DataFrame
 Row │ rowkey  b        c        d
     │ String  Float64  Float64  Float64
─────┼───────────────────────────────────
   1 │ x           1.0      3.0      1.0
   2 │ y           2.0      4.0      0.0
```